# How can I bind multiple ListViews within a single template?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controltemplate

I have a ControlTemplate for 3 ListViews.
Im Using the Template on a ListView eg.

```
Template="{StaticResource listViewTemplate}"
```

When i try to bind a Collection to the list views ItemsSource nothing happents.
If i Bind the Collection ItemsSource of the ControlTemplate it works fine.

The Problem is i have 3 ListViews using this ControlTemplate and i want to bind 3 different collections to the ListViews.

Is this possible?

Comment: can you add the more xaml which is not working for you ?

Comment: need more information, show us your template and the whole List declaration, also what type is your ItemSource - ObervableCollection List, Dictionary?

Comment: In situations like this, its usually best to create a prototype that attempts to do what you desire with the minimum amount of markup and code.  Not only can you use it to create a very good question, but you may also solve your question before you ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control template needs to bind its ItemsSource using TemplateBinding eg

```
<ControlTemplate ...>
    <ItemsSource = "{templateBinding ItemsSource}"
```

That will enable you to bind a collection on the list views ItemSource (this will get passed on to the ControlTemplates ItemsSource)

Answer (score 0):

Add `x:Shared="False"` to your static resource.  This will make sure a shallow copy of the object is made every time you request the resource.

This way each of your ListViews will get a different instance of the control template.

Here is the documentation on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx